# Loading ModalView only on first open

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've created a modal view that loads on top of my tabBar to serve as a 3 step welcome screen.

While all of that works OK, the problem I'm having is finding a way to load it only once, so that the user doesn't have to deal with a welcome message on every single load.

I've done some research, and it looks like I might be able to call a method with NSTimer, but I'm not sure if that's a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In your app delegate, set Bool and save in NSUserDefault Check if BOOL is set. If not then present view modally also set the BOOL.

Code might look like this:

In your appdelegate implementatuin. Application didFinishLaunching method:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstTimeBool"]) 
{  
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstTimeBool"];
   // present view controller modally after this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store this information in NSUserDefaults that exactly what's it is for :

At first start :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"IS_FIRST_LAUNCH"];
```

Then to know if it is the first time you run the app :

```
BOOL isFirstLaunch = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IS_FIRST_LAUNCH"] boolValue]
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent